# HMAC-SHA1 signatures in OCaml?

Tags: twitter, ocaml, sha1, hmac, reason

I'm trying to make requests to the Twitter API, and they require that I sign my requests. The final part of that requires signing via the HMAC-SHA1 hashing algorithm. Is there an easy way to get it?

Answer (score 3):

Hannes reached out to give me the answer (in ReasonML syntax below, rather than OCaml):

```
Nocrypto.Hash.SHA1.hmac key::(Cstruct.of_string signingKey) (Cstruct.of_string output) |> Cstruct.to_string
```

And with that, here's a signing function as translated from the [Twitter API doc](https://dev.twitter.com/oauth/overview/creating-signatures) (params and values are also taken from that page so output is verifiable as correct):

```
let signRequest clientId clientSecret method uri params :string => {
  let tmp = params |> List.sort (fun (a, _) (b, _) => compare a b);
  let collectedParamsString =
    List.map
      (
        fun (header: string, values: list string) => {
          let nextStr =
            List.fold_left
              (
                fun innerAcc value => {
                  let nextItem =
                    /* Using `Userinfo here is weird, but it's the only component I could get to properly percent-encode things in the same way Twitter expects it */
                    Uri.pct_encode component::`Query_key header ^
                    "=" ^ Uri.pct_encode component::`Userinfo value;
                  let final = innerAcc @ [nextItem];
                  print_endline (value ^ " => " ^ String.concat "&" final);
                  final
                }
              )
              []
              values |>
            String.concat "&";
          nextStr
        }
      )
      tmp |>
    String.concat "&";
  let output =
    String.uppercase_ascii method ^
    "&" ^
    Uri.pct_encode component::`Userinfo uri ^
    "&" ^ Uri.pct_encode component::`Userinfo collectedParamsString;
  let signingKey =
    Uri.pct_encode component::`Userinfo clientId ^
    "&" ^ Uri.pct_encode component::`Userinfo clientSecret;
  Cstruct.to_string (
    Nocrypto.Hash.SHA1.hmac key::(Cstruct.of_string signingKey) (Cstruct.of_string output)
  )
};

let signature =
  signRequest
    "post"
    "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
    "kAcSOqF21Fu85e7zjz7ZN2U4ZRhfV3WpwPAoE3Z7kBw"
    "LswwdoUaIvS8ltyTt5jkRh4J50vUPVVHtR2YPi5kE"
    [
      ("status", ["Hello Ladies + Gentlemen, a signed OAuth request!"]),
      ("include_entities", ["true"]),
      ("oauth_consumer_key", ["xvz1evFS4wEEPTGEFPHBog"]),
      ("oauth_nonce", ["kYjzVBB8Y0ZFabxSWbWovY3uYSQ2pTgmZeNu2VS4cg"]),
      ("oauth_signature_method", ["HMAC-SHA1"]),
      ("oauth_timestamp", ["1318622958"]),
      ("oauth_token", ["370773112-GmHxMAgYyLbNEtIKZeRNFsMKPR9EyMZeS9weJAEb"]),
      ("oauth_version", ["1.0"])
    ];
/* let signature : string = "hCtSmYh+iHYCEqBWrE7C7hYmtUk */
```

Edit: I originally stated that Hannes was the author of OCaml's nocrypto library - it's actually David Kaloper. Very sorry about that, and thank you to Daniel Bünzli for pointing that out!

Comment: Hannes is not the author of nocrypto. The author of nocrypto is David Kaloper. See https://opam.ocaml.org/packages/nocrypto/

Comment: Once I got the output from `Nocrypto.Hash.SHA1.hmac` I needed to run it through B64.encode to get `hCtSmYh+iHYCEqBWrE7C7hYmtUk=` to match your test case.